# Can you display a Splash Screen post launch?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

I'm trying to use QSplashScreen as a 'simple' notification window. I build the actual notification in a dialog and am then trying to use QPixmap.grabWidget() on that and pass the pixmap to the SplashScreen but its not showing. So I'm wondering if the problem is due to me trying to use it post-start.

Simplified version of what I'm doing.

```
class NotifyHandler:

    def showNotify(self, event):
        widget = NotifyWidget.createInstance(event) # Build the QDialog
        #Do I need to do widget.show()?
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(widget) # Convert to pixmap

        splash = QtGui.QSplashScreen(pixmap, QtCore.Qt.WindowStayOnTopHint)
        (x,y) = getDisplayLocation(splash) # Get coords to put it in bottom-right corner
        splash.setGeometry(splash.width(), splash.height(), x, y)

        splash.show()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, splash.close)
```

I try this however nothing shows up. If I try it as a Dialog though:

```
widget.show()
widget.raise_()
widget.activateWindow()
```

It works fine. So I figure either I can't do this post-launch or there is something going on when I try to feed it a pixmap of a widget. Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that. The dialog doesn't display normally anymore. So maybe my problem lies in there somewhere.

Comment: Also worth noting for future reference. My setGeometry is backwards, its x,y,w,h.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my dialog issue and splash screen were having the same sort of issue.

I forgot that if you don't assign the dialog (or Splash screen in this case) to a scope outside the method then the GC will just eat the object after the method returns.

So by simply adding something like:

```
self.splash = splash
self.splash.show()
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.splash.close)
```

The splash screen wouldn't be garbage collected and I get my splash screen.